# Accessing MySQL running on Docker Swarm

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-swarm

I have what is going to be a production MySQL database, and we want to access such remotely but haven't found a secure way to do it.

Docker Swarm do not have support for host bound ports such as 127.0.0.1:3303:3303, however normal mode does. Making a port public becomes also public in all swarm nodes.

Using firewalls is not really an option since we would have to configure these on every single node in the swarm.

We have on table only two options

Opening the port and only allowing connections through TLS and enforcing REQUIRE options Issuer and Subject, to only one single user and probably read_only. Still seems to be highly insecure due to having the open port.
Creating a temporary dockerized sshd service and making it available in the same network as MySQL service, it is more hazzle to manage these ssh containers. Still more secure since it would be turn on/off when needed
Question: Is there any other/better options to approach this? and how badly insecure is it to have open port + tls connections?

If you have a good argument against accessing MySQL remotely I would appreciate it

Comment: how about an nginx load balancer docker container with allowed hosts and deny hosts directives. there is an nginx-stream container you can get from docker-hub and do this.

Comment: Most cloud providers have security groups, i ended up exposing the ports to 3306 anyway, and accessing with mysql client tunneling though ssh